# bad interpreter: No such file or directory for 'bundle install '

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-rails

I am learning React on Rails. But when I added `react-rails` gem to gemfile to my Rails app and entered command: `bundle install`, I am getting following error.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec/rbenv-exec: 

/usr/local/bin/bundle: 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby:

bad interpreter: No such file ordirectory
```

Comment: seems like a problem with [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). Did you properly install and configure that? It looks like you are using homebrew, so check setup steps listed [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos)

Comment: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/646